# Difference in binary behaviour (execution/under debugger)

Tags: x86-64, lldb

I was trying out a simple heap overflow example (http://highaltitudehacks.com/2020/09/05/arm64-reversing-and-exploitation-part-1-arm-instruction-set-heap-overflow/) but replicated the relevant code in x86/x64 to understand it better. This is the code I used

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *name = malloc(0x6);
    char *command = malloc(0x6);
    strcpy(command,"whoami");
    strcpy(name,"zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzls -l");

    system(command);
}
```

I noticed that if I compiled the code and ran it normally, I will get system to execute "ls -l" and does a folder listing. However, if I was stepping through the binary using lldb from start to midway and proceed to continue the rest of the execution while inside lldb, I will see "whoami" executed instead.

I am testing this on a Mac OS and I am not sure if this is due to lldb or Mac OS behaviour?

Comment: Its possible that while debugging the heap chunks that get allocated are far apart or have some extra padding in between. Add `printf("%p : %p\n", name, command)` before `strcpy` to verify the addresses with and without debugger.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Its not related to RE in any way.

Comment: Thanks @sudhackar. Just curious though, my rationale for putting this in RE is because I was reversing it and the binary's behaviour looks different under lldb. Would it have been better if I posted this under Security Stack Exchange instead?

Comment: This was more of a "weird behaviour" question. Needs more looking around, not anything specific to RE.

Comment: Sorry just one more question. How did you know the exact difference was 0x10 (16 bytes)?

Comment: <address of `command`> - <address of `name`>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the overflow from `name` to `command` to work, the difference between the addresses of both should be 0x10 bytes.

I verified what I mentioned in the case earlier - Adding

```
printf("%p:%p\n", name, command);
```

Under a debugger stepping through main gives the addresses as

```
0x100404080:0x1002059f0
```

Here delta > 0x10 bytes and hence the `name` `strcpy` would not overflow to `command`

while without stepping or without a debugger comes out

```
0x7fa890405830:0x7fa890405840
```

exactly 0x10 bytes.